# How export Eclipse 3.7 rcp product with AspectJ support?

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, rcp

Everything works fine when testing rcp application within development environmment. But, aspects are not processed in exported product.
Documentation and threads on the web refer to many wizards that provide AspectJ support but those wizards seem to be missing in Ajdt 2.2.2. Someone may explain it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "aspects are not processed in exported product" mean? Do you see any errors? Do you use compile-time or load-time weaving? Can you show any code?

Comment: @kriaegaex In exported product, the aspects are not called. The reason of simple, when exporting the product, the standard compiler is called, not the aspect one. There's not error and that's normal. To get the aspects work in an exported product, a specific build have to be processed. In my installation, those specific exporters are missing (you can see them in the second screenshot at [http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/whatsnew14/]. To answer your question: it's compile-time weaving.

Comment: I have next to no experience with RCP, but have you tried with a more recent Eclipse version including newer AJDT and RCP versions? Maybe you are luckier with Luna 4.4 or even the brandnew Mars 4.5. Indigo 3.7 is 4 years old.